# Including a list of related entities in the Elasticsearch index

Tags: lucene, playframework, elasticsearch, playframework-1.x

Using the elasticsearch module, is it possible to somehow index the results of a related collection, which is lazy-loaded?

I have a model type Book, which has many Authors, which are lazy loaded

If I annotate the list of authors as @ElasticSearchEmbedded, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.Book.authors, no session or session was closed
```

If I mark it as ignored, of course everything goes fine. Is there a way to at least get the names of the authors in the Book index?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can load a lazy-loaded collection without loading it? Because that is how it sounds to me.

Comment: No, of course, that is not what I mean. I just want the collection to somehow get "indexed" by the elastic search plugin. Its fetch type is set to LAZY, and so it should remain. If I set it to eager, it kinda gets into the index